# Student seating in a class

Tags: combinatorics

A classroom has $2n$ students. The teacher writes down some subsets of $n$ students so that for any subset of all students which has an even size, at least one of the written subsets contains exactly half of these students. Can the teacher seat the students in a circle (with equal spacing) so that any semicircle is a written subset or its complement?

For instance, when $n=3$ the teacher can write down students $\{s_1,s_2,s_3\},\{s_1,s_2,s_4\},\{s_1,s_3,s_5\}$, then seat them in the order $s_1,s_2,s_4,s_6,s_5,s_3$. This seems to hold in general, but exhausting all cases is quite difficult even for this small $n$.

Comment: Can you define semicircle? For example, is the full circle and the empty circle valid? For example,  for $n=1$ and $\{\{s_1\}\}$, is this a counterexample because neither $(s_1,s_2)$ nor $()$ fulfill the criterion?

Comment: @NeitherNor A semicircle will contain $n$ consecutive seats. I'm not sure what you mean by "is the full circle and empty circle valid". For $n=1$, the teacher writes down ${s_1}$ and the seating of $s_1, s_2$ is valid.

Comment: So, a semi-circle contains exactly half of the students?

Comment: Yes, that seems like a reasonable interpretation, esp with the assumption that the $2n$ students are evenly distributed around the circle.

Comment: So,  choose $n=2$ and $\{\{s_1,s_2\}\}$. Since you have to seat them in a circle, $s_1$ must have either $s_3$ or $s_4$ as a neighbor. W.L.O.G. assume it's $s_3$. Then,  $(s_1,s_3)$ is a semicircle which serves as a counterexample.

Comment: Your example doesn't satisfy the condition. For example, the set $\{ s_1, s_2 \}$ does not intersect any written set in exactly 1 place. In order to fulfill the condition, the teacher would have to write down another subset, say $\{s_1, s_3\}$, from which we can form the circle $s_1, s_2, s_4, s_3$.

Comment: Calvin Lin is correct.

Comment: Sorry. I now get the question. But maybe you can improve its formulation because it is really prone to misunderstandings (->any subset of all students which has an even size).

Comment: What is the source of this problem? It might have been [posted in the last day but was removed by the author](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3881478/student-subset-in-a-class), so I'd like to ensure it's not a live ongoing content problem.

Comment: It is from some observations I made but couldn't verify, not from an ongoing contest (or any contest). The deleted question was by me (asking the more specific $n=3$)